# Where is the location of 'plugins' directory for eclipse mars in mac OSX?

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-mars

I was trying to install the eclipse plug-in for an assignment.
But the problem is, my installed eclipse's version is mars, which means I can not find the location of the 'plugins' directory, which was used to save plug-in jar files.

I've updated the eclipse Luna to Mars recently.
When I installed(unzipped) the eclipse luna, I remember that there was 'plugins' directory and other things (including eclipse.app) were in the 'eclipse' directory.
However, The mars, archive file just gives me an eclipse.app!..

Could you tell me how to add the plugin(*.jar, in my case, UMLet) to eclipse mars on Mac OSX?
I have to do my assignment.. The due is coming..

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Eclipse Mars on the Mac has been reworked to be a proper Mac application with everything included in the Eclipse.app package.

The new path for the plugins is

```
/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins
```

If you are looking at '/Applications' using the Mac Finder you will just see 'Eclipse'. You have to right click on 'Eclipse' and choose 'Show Package Contents' to see the contents.

Just putting things in the Eclipse plugins directory may not work. If at all possible you should use a proper Eclipse update site (sometimes called a repository) with 'Install New Software'.

Note most Eclipse installs now use 'oomph' which installs in a different location - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34333669/2670892)

Comment: Thank u sir! I Finally find the path! It is kinda shocking, because i spent huge amount of time to find the path, but it is literally 'in' the app. Anyway thanks again greg-449! All hail Greg!

Comment: @WarrenP There are still 'package' installs of Eclipse available which do install where I said - I am running such a version. The Eclipse downloads which use the oomph installer do install in the user's home directory.

Comment: Thanks. It's confusing that there are two installer types.  The oomph installer is the one most users get funnelled to and it puts plugins  in `~/.p2`

Comment: Please consider switching the accepted answer as this doesn't seem to apply when applications are signed or new ones are installed.  The other answer addresses these concerns.

Comment: @MarqueIV The OP was last on Stack Overflow in Dec 2015 so this is unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 54):

In my case (Mars on Mac version Darwin 14.5.0, installed with Eclipse installer) I found the plugins folder in `MY_HOME_DIRECTORY/.p2/pool/plugins` . I found this path with this: Eclipse -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Configuration -> property --launcher.library

Comment: Thanks for this. The plugins directory is certainly is a strange place when the Eclipse installer is used...

Comment: Thank you, this should be marked as the correct answer. Using @greg-449's method probably works as well - until you upgrade your version of Eclipse and replace the .app file.

Comment: In newer Mac OS with code signing, @greg-449's approach will fail with a corrupted application error.

Comment: For macOS Sierra, the plugin path is different from @Babu's response. I found mine by searching for "*** Current Install Configuration:" in the dialog he mentioned.

Comment: same place for me for neon on linux

Comment: @TCWan My approach does not cause a corrupted application error. I use this all the time and it works just fine. The difference here is some Eclipse downloads use the Oomph installer which uses the .p2 directory, but other downloads don't use the installer and put everything in the application folder.

Comment: @greg-449, have you ran that on a Mac with code-signing?  That's what this person is referring to.  You may have your checks disabled.

Comment: @MarqueIV As I already said there are several different downloads which behave differently. I use the [Eclipse Project downloads](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) which behave as I said, and don't give any issues. I do not have code signing turned off.

Comment: But as others have pointed out, when you update your Eclipse.app with a newer version, you're overwriting all of your plugins. Plus, when signing protection is turned on, you have modified the contents of the app directory, which generally isn't allowed in later versions of the os. But if you say it works for you, perhaps there's another setting we don't know about that is allowing it.  Lemme dig around and see what I can find out.

Answer (score 0):

you can use terminal add go to folder contain eclipse with has an icon, and use `ls -lrt` and you will see Eclipse.app in it. and `cd` to such folder and will see all things like windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Eclipse-path>/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse
```

You can check in below location from your terminal,

```
cd /Users/<user-name>/Downloads/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse
```

> where `<user-name>` is logged in mac user,
>   `<Eclipse-path>` is a location where Eclipse.app is saved

Comment: Don't think this is correct as the app is still in your downloads folder.

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crf53.jpg

You can find the installation folder in About Eclipse > Installation Details > Configurations.